# How do I configure a guardfile to monitor the app/helpers directory in a Ruby/Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

Using guard 2.12.8, I am trying to get guard to pay attention to files in the app/helpers directory.

I tried several things, the most recent of which is

```
  guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do
  require "guard/rspec/dsl"
  dsl = Guard::RSpec::Dsl.new(self)

  # RSpec files
  rspec = dsl.rspec
  watch(rspec.spec_helper) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_support) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_files)
  watch(%r{^(app/helpers)/.*})
```

I've read the docs for Guard, but haven't found specific docs for Guard::RSpec::Dsl.  Examples, but no actualy "Here's how it works" stuff.  Pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The Guard::RSpec::Dsl is just to cleanup the regexp soup in the Guardfile, nothing more:

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/lib/guard/rspec/dsl.rb#L52

If that's your whole Guardfile, you're missing out on the Rails part:

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/lib/guard/rspec/templates/Guardfile

There's already a rule for handling app files:

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/lib/guard/rspec/dsl.rb#L50

Also, guard-rspec won't know which specs/features to run based on which helper file changed - so you have to decide whether to run a unit test, or a feature test, or all tests.

Here's the code for mapping between "app file" (modules, helpers, concerns) and spec files:

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/lib/guard/rspec/dsl.rb#L13

(Notice how the spec name and path is based on the regexp capture from the modified file)

So given the app files are already watched:

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/lib/guard/rspec/dsl.rb#L50

If you have `app/helpers/foo_helper.rb`, the regexp will capture `helpers/foo_helper` which means a file called `spec/helpers/foo_helper_spec.rb` has to exist.

If a matching name doesn't exist, you'll need custom rules.

I guess some support for helpers could be added, but it's hard to guess which specs/features to run (controllers are already quite messy).

I have no feedback on issues people have with this (and what their project layout is), so it's hard for me to guess how to improve/document.